# Clip a raster to the exact outline of a vector (.shp) in R?

Tags: r, shapefile, r-raster

I want to clip a Raster Layer exactly to the outline of a shpfile in R.

```
  crop_rast      = crop (raster , extent(vector))                 # Crop
  mask_rast      = mask (crop_rast, vector)                       # Mask
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clipping raster using shapefile in R, but keeping the geometry of the shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073669/clipping-raster-using-shapefile-in-r-but-keeping-the-geometry-of-the-shapefile)

Comment: @Val No this solution is to keep the geometry of the vector (i.e WGS84). It doesn't work for me.

Comment: You need to post a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some data so that others can re-create the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 5):

One reason why this may not work for you could be that the vector and raster data have a different coordinate reference system.

It *does* work, with either the `raster` or the `terra` package. Here illustrated with `terra`:

```
library(terra)
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
v <- v[3,]
plot(r)
lines(v, lwd=2)

x <- crop(r, v)
## to add a little bit more space you could do
# x <- crop(r, ext(v) + .01)
y <- mask(x, v)
plot(y)
lines(v)
```

Comment: what is for the + .01?

Comment: I have added a comment