# Why does terra::rast change raster values from numeric to factor?

Tags: r, r-sf, terra

I need to clip the national landcover database raster to a watershed boundary vector. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073669/clipping-raster-using-shapefile-in-r-but-keeping-the-geometry-of-the-shapefile) post works for some of the watersheds I am working with, but not all of them. For the ones that it does not work with, the issue appears to be that the `mask` step results in an entirely empty raster. For sake of brevity of this post, I am not including an example of two watersheds where this works and does not work. The example below is for a watershed that did not work in the workflow in the post mentioned above.

My solution for the watersheds that the `mask` step does not work for is to instead reproject the raster to the vector's CRS, then perform the clip and mask. To do so, I need to use `terra::rast` to get a `SpatRaster` so I can use `terra::project`. While this works to clip and mask the raster, a new issue has come up, where `terra::rast` is changing the cell values of the raster from numeric (i.e. the NLCD ID, which I want) to factor (i.e. the NLCD Class), which would be okay BUT the strings are different...e.g. the NLCD legend has ID 81 as "Pasture/Hay" but this gets changed to "Hay/Pasture" when using `rast`. Thus, this prevents me from using `left_join` correctly.

My end goal is to reclassify (i.e. simplify to 8 classes) the NLCD using a custom legend and then calculate the percent land for each reclassified land use.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
library(streamstats) # devtools::install_github("markwh/streamstats")
library(FedData)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# create the custom reclassified legend (needed below):

legend<-pal_nlcd()%>%mutate(ID2=c(1,2,3,3,3,3,2,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,2,2,6,7,8,8))
legend_2<-data.frame(ID2 = unique(legend$ID2))%>% mutate(Class2 = c("Open Water", "Other", "Developed", "Forest", "Grassland", "Pasture/Hay", "Cultivated Crops", "Wetlands"))
legend<-left_join(legend, legend_2, by = 'ID2')

# download the watershed boundary and convert to sf:

setTimeout(400)
ws1 <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = -73.65167, ylocation = 42.93556, crs = 4326,includeparameters = "false") # takes a minute to run
ws1_sp<-toSp(ws1, what = 'boundary') # also takes a minute to run
ws1_sf<-st_as_sf(ws1_sp)

# download the NLCD raster data:

nlcd<-get_nlcd(template = ws1_sf,label = 'HUDSON RIVER AT STILLWATER NY',year = 2016)

# convert to SpatRaster, reproject to vector's crs, then clip and mask:

nlcd_rast<-rast(nlcd)
nlcd_rast<-project(nlcd_rast, crs(ws1_sf))
nlcd_rast<-crop(nlcd_rast, raster::extent(ws1_sf))
nlcd_rast<-mask(nlcd_rast, ws1_sf)

# calculate the percent land of the reclassified land uses:

nlcd_df<-as.data.frame(nlcd_rast, xy = FALSE)%>%
  drop_na()%>%
  rename(ID = NLCD.Land.Cover.Class)%>%
  left_join(.,legend[,c(1,2,5,6)], by = c('ID'='Class'))%>%
  group_by(Class2)%>%
  summarise(n = n())%>%
  mutate(pland = round(n / sum(n), 4))%>%
  arrange(Class2)%>%
  dplyr::select(c(1,3))%>%
  complete(., Class2 = unique(legend$Class2), fill = list(pland = NA))
```

What I am trying to understand is 1) why `terra::rast` actually changes the rasters cell values in the first place:

```
class(as.data.frame(nlcd, xy = FALSE)$NLCD.Land.Cover.Class) # numeric
class(as.data.frame(nlcd_rast, xy = FALSE)$NLCD.Land.Cover.Class) # factor
```

and 2) why are the string values changed from the NLCD legend (which comes from the function `pal_nlcd()` used above)? If the class names were the same after using `terra::rast` as the NLCD legend, the `left_join` would work by 'Class', but this is not the case since I am missing some classes in my final result, `nlcd_df`. Here you can see how Pasture/Hay in the NLCD legend is switched to Hay/Pasture when using `terra::rast`:

```
unique(as.character(as.data.frame(nlcd_rast, xy = FALSE)$NLCD.Land.Cover.Class))
 [1] "Evergreen Forest"             "Herbaceous"                  
 [3] "Open Water"                   "Woody Wetlands"              
 [5] "Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands" "Shrub/Scrub"                 
 [7] "Deciduous Forest"             "Barren Land"                 
 [9] "Mixed Forest"                 "Developed, Open Space"       
[11] "Developed, Low Intensity"     "Developed, Medium Intensity" 
[13] "Developed, High Intensity"    "Hay/Pasture"                 
[15] "Cultivated Crops"            
> legend$Class
 [1] "Open Water"                   "Perennial Ice/Snow"          
 [3] "Developed, Open Space"        "Developed, Low Intensity"    
 [5] "Developed, Medium Intensity"  "Developed High Intensity"    
 [7] "Barren Land (Rock/Sand/Clay)" "Deciduous Forest"            
 [9] "Evergreen Forest"             "Mixed Forest"                
[11] "Dwarf Scrub"                  "Shrub/Scrub"                 
[13] "Grassland/Herbaceous"         "Sedge/Herbaceous"            
[15] "Lichens"                      "Moss"                        
[17] "Pasture/Hay"                  "Cultivated Crops"            
[19] "Woody Wetlands"               "Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands"
```

Also if you are having trouble installing `streamstats` you may need to try these steps first:

```
# step 1 - restart R

# Session->Restart R

# step 2 - add Rtools to PATH

old_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(old_path, "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin", sep = ";"))

# now try:

devtools::install_github("markwh/streamstats")

library(streamstats)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but here is how you can compute proportions of land cover classes.

```
library(FedData)
library(sf)
library(terra)

xy <- matrix(c(-73.9, 42.9, -73.9, 43, -73.92, 42.9), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
v <- vect(xy, "polygon", crs="+proj=lonlat")

nlcd <- get_nlcd(template=v,label = 'HUDSON RIVER AT STILLWATER NY',year = 2016)
nlcd <- rast(nlcd)

vr <- project(v, crs(nlcd))
nlcd2 <- crop(nlcd, vr, mask=TRUE)

f2 = freq(nlcd2)
f2$perc <- round(100 * f2$count / sum(f2$count), 1)
f2
#   layer                        value count perc
#1      1                   Open Water     4  0.0
#2      1        Developed, Open Space  1489 14.1
#3      1     Developed, Low Intensity  1066 10.1
#4      1  Developed, Medium Intensity   251  2.4
#5      1     Developed High Intensity    60  0.6
#6      1 Barren Land (Rock/Sand/Clay)    20  0.2
#7      1             Deciduous Forest   385  3.7
#8      1             Evergreen Forest   174  1.7
#9      1                 Mixed Forest  2228 21.1
#10     1                  Shrub/Scrub    29  0.3
#11     1         Grassland/Herbaceous    34  0.3
#12     1                  Pasture/Hay  2812 26.7
#13     1             Cultivated Crops   235  2.2
#14     1               Woody Wetlands  1713 16.3
#15     1 Emergent Herbaceous Wetlands    36  0.3
```

Note that I project the vector data. It is a mistake to project the raster data (it is inefficient and leads to data quality loss).

Comment: I appreciate the response. I asked this question to better understand the behavior of `terra::rast` because I need to reclassify the NLCD classes. Also for some reason when I run the exact code you posted, it still is Hay/Pasture instead of Pasture/Hay, which is a big deal for the reclassification via `left_join`. I understand there are ways of working around this specifically, but I am still very interested why the cell values of `rast(RasterLayer)` are different than the original `RasterLayer`. I can't find it anywhere in `?rast` why this would be the case.

Comment: I do not see any of that. If you see "Hay/Pasture" instead of "Pasture/Hay" you probably have some old or other data in the same download folder that creates a problem

Comment: Thank you - uninstalling and reinstalling FedData solved my issues.